# Mathematic definitions of some specific sets

Tags: notation

I want to define a set in the following form:

$$A = \{(u,v)~|~ u \in E, v\in F  \}.$$ Evidently each element in this set comprises of two values. Is there a specific definition of such set? Or can I call this set like "a set consisting of blabla" with "blabla" represents the mathematical definition of "(u,v)" ?

Comment: Your definition is fine. It’s a set consisting of ordered pairs of values. In fact it is $E\times F$ (Cartesian product).

Comment: It’s worth noting, in axiomatic set theory, it requires proof that this is a set. Using the standard definition of ordered pairs, it is a subset of $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(E\cup F)).$

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the "Cartesian Product" of $E$ and $F$. The standard notation is $E\times F$.